# Creating cron on RHEL 7 server to delete files older than a week

Tags: linux, bash, cron, rhel

I have log files which have the format as `catalina.2020-08-06.log`

I want to set a `cron job` which deletes all the above log files that are older than one week

I am using `crontab -e` to write the cron

Then, written the following cron:

```
0 11 * * * rm -rf /var/logs/catalina.2020-*
```

How to update above cron so that it deletes only the files which are older than one week?

Comment: Run:  `find /var/log/catalina.*.log -mtime +7 -type f`.  If this lists the files you want to delete, then use:  `0 11 * * * find /var/log/catalina.*.log -mtime +7 -type f -delete`

Comment: thanks a lot. this works!!